# Bash - Stripping and adding leading zeros to numbers before concatenating into string ordered strings

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I need to automate a backup solution which stores files in folders such as YYYYMMDD.nn.
Every day few files would be backed up like this so the resulting folder names could be 20141002.01, 20141002.2 ... 20141002.10. My current script works for YYYYMMDD.n but when n is more than 9 sorting  and picking up the last folder doesn't work because 20141002.10 is above 20141002.9 hens switching to YYYYMMDD.nn format and the approach of separating the nn, stripping leading zeros, then incrementing, and adding leading zeros if needed.
I have a function which checks the last folder for today's date and creates the next one.

```
createNextProcessedFolder() {
      local LastFolderName=`ls -1 ${ProcessedListsDir} | grep ${CurrentDate} | tail -n 1`
      n=`echo ${LastFolderName} | sed -r 's/^.{9}//'`
      n="$((10#$n))"
      nextFolderName=${CurrentDate}.$((if[[ $(( ${n}+1 )) < 10 ]];then n="0$((${n}+1))";else n="$(( ${n}+1 ))"; fi))
      mkdir ${ProcessedListsDir}/${nextFolderName}
      if [[ -d ${ProcessedListsDir}/${nextFolderName}  ]]
      then
          echo "New folder ${nextFolderName} was created"
      else
          echo "Error: ${nextFolderName} was not created"
      fi
      Location="${ProcessedListsDir}/${nextFolderName}"
}
```

So when I try to run this I get an error like:

```
line 21: if[[ 1 < 10 ]];then n="01";else n="1"; fi: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ";then n="01";else n="1"; fi")
```

Line 21 is:

```
nextFolderName=${CurrentDate}.$((if[[ $(( ${n}+1 )) < 10 ]];then n="0$((${n}+1))";else n="$(( ${n}+1 ))"; fi))
```

I'm sure there will be more errors after this one but I would really appreciate if somebody helped me with this.

Comment: also space between `if` and `[[`   try this : `if [[ 1 < 10 ]];then n="01";else n="1"; fi `

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot use `$((...))` for command substitution as it needs to be `$(...)`
- You need spaces before and after `[[` and `]]`. You can also use `((...))` in BASH:

Try this:

```
(( (n+1) < 10 )) && n="0$((n++))" || ((n++))
nextFolderName="${CurrentDate}.${n}"
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, you certainly put me not he right track. The n+1 didn't work for some strange reason so only 10 and above would work with n++. Nevertheless with your valuable input I managed to get it working with the code in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, another solution is:

```
n=$( printf "%02d" $n )
```

The `02` before the `d` means prepend with `0`s up to 2 digits. Or:

```
nextFolderName="${CurrentDate}."$( printf "%02d" "$n" )
```

Comment: Thanks @zerodiff . I like your solution because I can use it with any number of zeros, the "0$n" approach will only work for 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was with incrementing a number witch was extracted from a string with a leading zero and then returning the incremented number with a leading zero if smaller than 10. The solution I ended up using can be represented with the below script. 
I guess it can't be shorter than that

```
n=$1
(( ((n++)) < 10 )) && n="0$n"
echo $n
```

Something I didn't expect is that I don't have to strip leading zeros from n using this, n++ does it while incrementing :-)
Thanks again [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) for pointing me in the right direction.